# array_rand() does not work on getResult()

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use array_rand() for random entity selection after getResult(). 
I expect to get an random entity but got int 1(int 2, int 3 etc) instead. Why?

```
    $qb2->select('u')
        ->from('Application\Entity\User', 'u')
        ->where('u.usrlId = :sale');
    if( !empty($usersIdListForExcluding) ) {
        $qb2->andWhere($qb2->expr()->notIn( 'u.usrId', $usersIdListForExcluding ));
    }
    $qb2->setParameter('sale', 2);
    $salesSet = $qb2
        ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

    var_dump(array_rand($salesSet));

    var_dump($salesSet);
```

First var_dump gives:

```
int 1
```

Second one:

```
array (size=3)
0 => 
    object(DoctrineORMModule\Proxy\__CG__\Application\Entity\User)[552]
  public '__initializer__' => 
    object(Closure)[528]
  public '__cloner__' => 
    object(Closure)[529]
  public '__isInitialized__' => boolean true
  private 'usrId' (Application\Entity\User) => int 2
  private 'usrName' (Application\Entity\User) => string 'sales_test_1' (length=12)
  private 'usrPassword' (Application\Entity\User) => string 'pass' (length=4)
  private 'usrEmail' (Application\Entity\User) => string 's_1@gmail.com' (length=13)
      ...
  1 => 
    object(Application\Entity\User)[567]
  private 'usrId' => int 6
  private 'usrName' => string 'sales_test_3' (length=12)
  private 'usrPassword' => string 'pass' (length=4)
  private 'usrEmail' => string 's_3@gmail.com' (length=13)
  private 'usrlId' => int 2
      ...
  2 => 
     object(Application\Entity\User)[526]
  private 'usrId' => int 7
  private 'usrName' => string 'sales_test_4' (length=12)
  private 'usrPassword' => string 'pass' (length=4)
  private 'usrEmail' => string 's_4@gmail.com' (length=13) 
      ...
```

Comment: you should have started by reading the manual. It's written plainly, at the start of the documentation for array_rand(), that it returns an integer with a random entry. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_rand` returns a random key (as opposed to a random value). If you want the value then you can access it via the key.

```
$random_key = array_rand($salesSet);
$random_value = $salesSet[$randomKey];
```